# Android getting path to image from Thumbnail?

Tags: android, gridview, path, thumbnails

I'm trying to ship a pivotal update to my app currently on the market. I need to query the thumbnails in the MediaStore, and load the the thumbnails into a GridView. So far so good, now I just need to get the path of the actual fullsized image on the user's External Storage based only on what I have(which is the path to the thumbnail). I need to be able to perform 4 actions whenever a user clicks a thumbnail, Share, View, Move and Delete...but I can't do any of these with just the thumbnail path, I've tried everything, doesn't work :/. Here's a snippet of my implementation below, any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    int columnIndex = 0;
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);

    if(cursor != null){
        columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

        FileInputStream is = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;

        try{
            is = new FileInputStream(new File(imagePath));
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            useThisBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight(), true);

            bitmap.recycle();
        }catch(Exception e){
            //Try to recover
        }
        finally{
            try{
                if(bis != null){
                    bis.close();
                }
                if(is != null){
                    is.close();
                }
                cursor.close();
                projection = null;
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "  " + imagePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

So far I've tried everything using the imagePath member, but that either causes exceptions to be thrown or other errors. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution. Before I was querying the MediaStore Content Resolver and grabbing Thumbnails(not what I needed anyways). This optimization allows me to search the MediaStore in the same exact way, but this time I'm searching for the ACTUAL Images, and I'm returning the Thumbnail MICRO_KIND. The images are then cached in an array of Bitmaps and then used to populate the GridView. I am now able to get the path to the actual, full size image on the device..in case I need to create a URI instance or a File using that path, now I can easily. For anyone else having this or a similar issue [Android getting path to image from Thumbnail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279553/android-getting-path-to-image-from-thumbnail), here's the solution code below. Btw, I'm doing this in an AsyncTask and showing/dismissing a loading dialog after all images on device have been displayed.

```
  /*----------------------------ASYNC TASK TO LOAD THE    PHOTOS--------------------------------------------------------*/

public class LoadPhotos extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;

        Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                null, orderBy);

        int image_column_index = imagecursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

        AllPhotosActivity.count = imagecursor.getCount();
        AllPhotosActivity.windows = new Bitmap[AllPhotosActivity.count];

        for (int i = 0; i < AllPhotosActivity.count; i++) {
            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            //i = index;
            int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
            windows[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        }

        imagecursor.close();
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();
        imagegrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }



}
```

And here's my onItemClick()
The "filename" member is what you would use to create instances of URIs or whatever you need to do with the image.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, android.view.View v,
                int position, long id) {
            String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
            Cursor actualimagecursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
                    null, null, null);

            final int dataColumnIndex = actualimagecursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            final int idColumIndex = actualimagecursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

            actualimagecursor.moveToPosition(position);

            filename = actualimagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
            final long imageId = actualimagecursor.getLong(idColumIndex);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this code,but it is not giving exact path of the selected image.When am selecting the 1st image it is giving path of 2nd image.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
```

use this code, i think it will work. Basically its the same id for both thumbnail and the original image, so the position for both thumbnails and images will be the same.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. As you can see I'm already using the code you posted. A more detailed solution please.

Comment: I've tried your code. It doesn't work, as I'm getting random Uris from the MediaStore and not the one for the fullsize image