# How to get imagepath from thumbnail path of a image?

Tags: android

I am trying to get imagepath based on thumbail path , i have already tried solution from 
[android-getting-path-to-image-from-thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279553/android-getting-path-to-image-from-thumbnail), but it is based on gridview position, i am only retrieving specific images. Also i found one sample code from SO, the code is

```
private String getImagePathFromThumbPath(String thumbPath)
    {
        String imgPath=null;

//      String[] projection = new String[] {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID};
        String[] imagesDataPath={ MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA ,MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
            //mResolver.query() requires android API 16
        Cursor thumbnails = mResolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imagesDataPath,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA+"=?",new String[]{thumbPath}, null, null);

        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor imageCursor = mResolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, filePathColumn, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?", new String[] {thumbId}, null);

        if (imageCursor != null && imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            // Your file-path will be here
            imgPath= imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]));
        }
        return imgPath;
    }
```

The above method is bit modified to suit my needs and it returns nothing on Toasting, please tell how to retrieve imagepath using thumbnail path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a long time and relentless try, the solution is here

**1.** You need to find the image id which is image unique id from images table in thumbnail table, query to thumbnail provider ([MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html#EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)) if you do not understand it, refer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html) , specifically [IMAGE_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html#IMAGE_ID),

**Step 1** is to get `retrievedImageId`.

```
retrievedImageId = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(imageIdInImages));
```

**2.** Now using the `retrievedImageId` get the image path, by again querying the content provider, only this time query the Images media provider ([MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI))

```
String getImagePathFromThumbPath(String thumbPath)
    {
        String imagePath = null;

        if(thumbPath != null )
        {
            String[] columns_to_return = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID};
            String where = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA+" LIKE ?";
            long retrievedImageId = -1;
            String valuesAre[] = {"%"+thumbPath};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns_to_return, where, valuesAre, null);
            if(cursor != null)
            {           
                int imageIdInImages = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);

                for (cursor.moveToFirst();!cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) 
                {
                       //STEP 1 to retrieve image ID
                   retrievedImageId = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(imageIdInImages));
                }

                if(retrievedImageId != -1)
                {
                    // STEP 2 Now
                    Log.i(TAG, "imageId-" + retrievedImageId);
                    String[] columnsReturn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    String whereimageId = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID+" LIKE ?";
                    String valuesIs[] = {"%" + retrievedImageId};
                    Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columnsReturn, whereimageId, valuesIs, null);
                    int rawDataPath= mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                    for (mCursor.moveToFirst();!mCursor.isAfterLast(); mCursor.moveToNext()) 
                    {
                        imagePath = mCursor.getString(rawDataPath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }   

        return imagePath;
    }
```

If you still have doubt or error/exception, leave comment!

Comment: What exactly is "EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI" used for? is it for content that is available for all apps, hence they don't need permissions? Also, given a uri from outside of your app (via an intent), how would you know its source(app that sent it), and whether or not it has any extra information (time taken, etc...) ?

Comment: I am getting path but its of different image.

Comment: @calvin: what id are you passing? are you sure its the different image. Feel free to ask another question based on it, if it is too long.

Comment: @AkhilJain I posted question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839329/get-reference-of-actual-image-from-mediastore-images-thumbnails-table

Comment: @AkhilJain: it works perfect in lollipop. but not on 4.1.2 :(