# How to get the uri of the images stored in the phone and return them in a String[]

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-image

I am trying to create a custom gallery with a single select option. I've used the code  provided by [google docs to create a GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) that contains the images contained in drawable.
Now I want to change it by making the GridView show all the images stored in the phone.

Comment: Please show what you've done so far.

Comment: i have done exactly the same as they say in the google docs link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

To get all images from the phone you need to query the android.provider.MediaStore

First make sure you have the AndroidPermission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, then get the thumbnails for the grid.
Here is a simple way to do this:

[HERE](https://www.codota.com/android/scenarios/51891806da0af61a57cb113c/android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media?tag=out_2013_05_05_07_19_34&afterAuth=%2Fandroid%2Fscenarios%2F51891806da0af61a57cb113c%2Fandroid.provider.MediaStore%24Images%24Media%3Ftag%3Dout_2013_05_05_07_19_34%26fullSource%3D1)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your help, the code works but it don't get the thumbnails !!

Comment: try this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172074/get-images-thumbnail-file-paths