# Acquire thumbnail file paths in the new API 29

Tags: java, android

I am working on a gallery app and I am using the solution from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18304390/9785472

To iterate over the images, find their thumbanils paths, and finally store them for later use. This works fine until API29.

I have found out that they have deprecated the entire `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails` class in API29.

I have tried searching for a way to acquire the thumbnail paths without luck. They only mentioned `loadThumbnail` on `ContentResolver` as an alternative which returns a `Bitmap` only.

Is there any way to acquire the thumbnails paths on API29, that are generated by `loadThumbnail()`?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Probably not. You would not have access to the files anyway, once your app starts using scoped storage.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info, CommonsWare. After reading on the scoped storage. I believe I understand your comment. From what I have read on the scoped storage, they would allow us access to files in MediaStores for images, audio, and videos. What I do not get is why they did not keep the thumbnails MediaStore. I also do not understand why Google chose the cancer storage approach that will restrict both users and developers. What Google should do is offer this as an optional feature (like it does now) and not force it.