# Android :Get both Thumbnailpath and Imagepath from Gallery

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I am little stuck on a query. searched a lot but didn't get desired result..So please help me to Solve this problem..

I want to Select Image from Gallery and I got success in it.. but now I want to get thumbnail path too..
I know I can Create Thumbnail From Image path...but **i want string path of thumbnail** so i can use it in array....

So When I select any image from gallery I want these two paths..

1. Image Path
2. **Thumbnail Path** or **ID of Selected Image**

**My Code..**

to Open Gallery..

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

**OnActivityResult()**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    path = null;

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        long imageId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex); //getting 0 here... i thought it could give me image id.. :p 
        Log.v("AddEventDataActivity", "Selected Image Path : " + path); // getting image path successfully...
        Log.v("AddEventDataActivity", "Selected Image ID : " + imageId); // ??? 
        cursor.close();

        // tried this but not succeed.. :(
        Cursor thumbcursor = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails
                .queryMiniThumbnail(getContentResolver(), imageId,
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);

        if (thumbcursor != null && thumbcursor.getCount() > 0) {
            thumbcursor.moveToFirst();// **EDIT**
            thumbpath = thumbcursor.getString(thumbcursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
        }
        thumbcursor.close();

        Log.v("THUMB", "THUMBNAIL PATH : " + thumbpath); // no value to thumbpath...

    } 
}
```

I could not find how to solve that...
Any help would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

for getting Thumbnail

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                             getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri,
                             MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                             (BitmapFactory.Options) null );
```

where `selectedImageUri = data.getData();`

Comment: can i get thumbnail path from it??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548922/how-to-get-imagepath-from-thumbnail-path-of-a-image

Comment: getThumbnail can not use URI... it needs to be LONG value... 

Syntax : getThumbnail(ContentResolver, long, int, BitmapFactory.Options)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but this worked for me:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        try {
            Long thumbId = Long.parseLong(selectedImage.getLastPathSegment());

            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    getContentResolver(),
                    thumbId,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                    null
            );
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //Handle exception
        }
    }
}
```